# sending smtp mail with PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer to send email from a contact form. using the following code, I get the message "message sent" yet nothing ever arrives. I've tried both with my AOL account and Gmail account.

```
<?php
$mail = new PHPMailer();

    // ---------- adjust these lines ---------------------------------------
    $mail->Username = "account@aol.com"; // your user name
    $mail->Password = "password";  // your Password
    $mail->AddAddress("recipient@company.com"); // recipients email
    $mail->FromName = "My name"; // readable name

    $mail->Subject = "Message from BeaverMjr.info";
    $mail->Body    = $body; 

    $mail->Host = "smtp.aol.com";
    $mail->Port = 587; //465 or 587
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->From = $mail->Username;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
        echo "mail sent";
    }
?>
```

I've been scratching my head as I search the net and am getting no where. can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: check SPAM folder and wait some time, it may be delay caused by grey tables.

Comment: `if(!$mail->Send())
    {
        echo "mail sent";
    }` ...this logic is backwards. Lose the `!`

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting the `mail sent` message it actually did not send because your `if` statement has the `NOT` operator in front of it.

I'd advise you set `$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;` and then update your code to see what the error message is:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected my code and found that I had a connection error. After further review, I figured out that the port number needed to be 25. Thanks for the help.